# Do alpaca socks have the best fit for skiing?

Tags: skiing, socks

I was recommended alpaca socks but I have never used this type of wool before, I would like to know if they are right choice for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Real alpaca is a lot like merino wool. It shares many of the same great qualities. One cool quality of alpaca is it's hollow fibers are very good at insulating. But for ski socks I'm not sure you necessarily need or want that insulation unless your feet get cold really quickly. Another important quality of ski socks is that they should be thin. This helps transfer the motion faster to the boots making them more responsive. The textile industry has developed more around merino wool than alpaca so you probably won't be able to find as thin of a alpaca sock. Alpaca is also VERY expensive. A lot of "alpaca" products outside of reputable retailers tend to not actually be alpaca so be careful.

Merino wool socks are probably going to be as good or better for skiing at a lower cost. Alpaca has it's uses, for example I love my alpaca beanie, but for ski socks it probably isn't the material I'd want. I personally use merino wool socks made by Mons Royale for skiing and snowboarding. I'm quite happy with them and have bought 5 pairs (I also use them for whitewater so they see a fair bit of abuse) over the last ~6 years.

All this said, alpaca socks would be much better than most other materials for skiing. It's an incredibly high performance fiber.

Answer (score 2):

I can assure you that Alpaca Wool is indeed warmer than all common fabrics used to produce socks, because of its natural thermal adaptability for variable weather. [Here](https://www.alpacacollections.com/blog/alpaca-socks-warmer-than-wool/) it is explained a little better:

> The reason why is due to alpaca's fiber nature. Alpaca is a hollow-core fiber. This is the reason why Alpaca clothing is naturally insulating. The air gets trapped in the inner core of the fiber and the moisture naturally wicks up and out, keeping your feet dry, which allows Alpaca Socks to keep your feet up to 3 times warmer than wool.

Another feature I enjoy most about this material is that it is extra lightweight, the sock stays in place for maximum protection without extra bulk. They are my favorite for winter sports.

I would highly recommend them!